# Modal windows aren't responding in Microsoft Edge (Spartan)

Tags: jquery-ui, microsoft-edge

We are testing our site in Microsoft Edge (Spartan) and in our site we are extensively using jQuery modal windows. When we open those jQuery modal windows in Spartan browser, the modal window does open, but the modal window is not responding. I mean, I am not able to do any action in that modal window such as click any button or enter any text etc. But the same functionality is working fine in IE 11 in Windows 10.

Comment: do you see any errors in the developer tools console? can you share us your markup?

Comment: No errors in the developer console. This is the sample markup I am using. I am also using knockout js for data binding

Comment: <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <label class="DetailLabel">Business Division Name <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="inputName" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 DetailDropdown" data-bind="value: BusinessDivisionName" style="margin-left:15px;" maxlength="50">  
            <img style="vertical-align: text-top;margin-left:13px;" alt="Help" src="/content/images/icon_info.png" title="The business division name that is being used in the OSS approval tool">

Comment: @PremchandPeddakotla I have create a jsfiddle in my answer below that shows the modal window working. if you can check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug it Microsoft Edge using the developer tools F12. It is working now. check out this JSFiddle I created that shows a modal window in action. http://jsfiddle.net/dj8kobvy/

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">

  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>

</div>
```

> $(function() {
>       $( "#dialog" ).dialog(); });